# Cisco Nexus C9396PX licence question

Tags: cisco, switch, cisco-nexus, license

We have Cisco Nexus C9396PX and i want to run `HSRP` on this to do failover, I just looked at licence and its showing following does that mean switch has activated Layer 3 license?

```
switch# show lic u
Feature                      Ins  Lic   Status Expiry Date Comments
                                 Count
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
LAN_ENTERPRISE_SERVICES_PKG   No    -   Unused             -
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

What does about output meas?

Comment: That license has nothing to do with HSRP. LAN enterprise covers: OSPF, BGP IS-IS, PIM, SSM, MSDP, Policy based routing, GRE tunneling, EIGRP, VRF leaking, VXLAN and BGP eVPN.

Comment: HSRP requires no license. Any feature not included in a license package is bundled with the nx-os image and is provided at no extra charge. To activate HSRP simply use: `switch(config)# feature hsrp`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The LAN_ENTERPRISE_SERVICES_PKG license has nothing to do with HSRP. LAN enterprise covers: OSPF, BGP, IS-IS, PIM, SSM, MSDP, Policy based routing, GRE tunneling, EIGRP, VRF route leaking, VXLAN and BGP eVPN.

HSRP requires no license. Any feature not included in a license package is bundled with the nx-os image and is provided at no extra charge. To activate HSRP simply use:

```
switch(config)# feature hsrp
```

Nexus 9000 series HSRP configuration guide:

https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/datacenter/nexus9000/sw/6-x/unicast/configuration/guide/l3_cli_nxos/l3_hsrp.html#52265

As rnxrx has correctly mentioned in the comment, there's a difference between the Nexus switches and what basic features are supported. Therefore i've added the below license matrix for all Nexus switches and all licenses possible to add:

https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/datacenter/sw/nx-os/licensing/guide/b_Cisco_NX-OS_Licensing_Guide/b_Cisco_NX-OS_Licensing_Guide_chapter_01.html

Comment: You said all nx-os default support HSRP, does that apply to Nexus  3064 switch too

Comment: @Satish Yes pretty sure it does.

Comment: Thanks! But as per my output do you think I have Enterprise license and I can run BGP on it? I want whatever license we have activated or expired.

Comment: So in my output `Ins` is `NO` means license not installed but wondering if license not installed then `show lic u` output should be empty

Comment: The 3K and 9K have different license terms.  ANY L3 on the 3K requires a license while on a 9K basic L3 is supported without any additional license.

Comment: @Satish Yes with that license you can run BGP on your Nexus. I don't remember what the output is, if the license is not installed. I think it might show the available license, just like your output.

Comment: @rnxrx I've added the Cisco license matrix for all Nexus switches and all possible addons to the different versions.

Comment: @rnxrx By the way, HSRP IS supported on all NX-OS versions no matter what Nexus series. See [https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/datacenter/nexus3000/sw/unicast/nexus3000_unicast_config_gd_503_u1_1/l3_hsrp.html#wp1477523](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/datacenter/nexus3000/sw/unicast/nexus3000_unicast_config_gd_503_u1_1/l3_hsrp.html#wp1477523) While the feature can be enabled at no cost, layer 3 is required to make use of HSRP. But maybe that is what you meant?

Comment: Basically all features on the 9K/3k are honors-based.  You can enable the feature but that doesn’t mean it’s actually licensed.

Comment: This is getting interesting, You are saying I can enable HSRP but I need to get L3 license to make it work, how do I verify L3 is supported?  Is there anyway command I can run and tell us L3 not licensed ?

Comment: @Satish Only on the Nexus 3000 series.

Comment: So I need L3 license for 3064 switch but not on N9K

Comment: @Satish Yes that is correct.

Comment: Thanks I'm going to order one now :) and for N9K it has built in L3 support so we are good. I would say can your put notes in your answer saying in some cases L3 license trwuired to run HSRP so people like me have clear picture :)